# How to capture SWF packets?

Tags: flash, packet

I have a swf that retrive information from a xml file, but I do not know url of the xml. Is it possible to capture tcp/ip packet when swf start retriving information from the xml? I would like to know url of the xml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the Firefox extension [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/1843). It has a nice graph/option to show any web-traffic. Btw. feel free to give us the link to the swf file. We will be happy to help you find the xml you are talking about.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at http://www.wireshark.org/ It should do the trick.

Comment: Assuming this is out of the browser, else firebug is the easier option as per merkuro's answer